# Node js server: I want to respond to a browser request with both HTML and JSON in the same response, is this possible?

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js, response

Basically, my thought process is as follows.

Client/browser requests `html` file `login.html`. This file contains a form with a `username` and `password` field. The submission button sends a `POST` request to the server with the given user and password field values. Simple, so far.

The server then checks a folder `/users` of `JSON` files of the naming convention `username.json`. For instance, if the client submits the username "John", it checks to see whether or not the file `John.json` exists. If it does, it compares the password value submitted in the `POST` request to that of the `JSON` file. If that matches, it returns the `login-success` html file, otherwise redirects back home.

That's where my problem lies. If it succeeds, I also wan't it to 'respond' with the JSON file matched to it, but the request seemingy only allows for the response to be one content-type, or to be read from a single file.

So, I'm just not sure how the client will know which `JSON` file to read based on the given response. I'm sure there's an easy solution and that I'm being an idiot, but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: HTML and JSON is just text, so while it's possible, it doesn't necessarily make sense.

Comment: Put the JSON in a SCRIPT block in the HTML response.

Comment: @FelixKling Yeah, ultimately they can both be boiled down to plain text objects and then just interpreted by the browser as HTML...I was just wondering if there's any elegant way of passing the client the json file matched on the server in the same request. I'm starting to think there isn't one, though.

Comment: @Diodeus I might go with this. I considered this, it just seemed...messy?

Comment: @JonathanBrooks: It entirely depends on how you want to consume the JSON

Comment: @SLaks Can you elaborate? Basically, the JSON file which is matched on the server will also contain user preferences, file associations etc. which I want the client side script to use. I just don't know how to pass this file, or even filename, to the client side from the server side.

Comment: Nope, it's not elegant, but it's probably the easiest to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I decided to use the `Sockets.io` module in order to pass the client my json data.
This enabled me to open up a TCP connection on the back of my HTTP server between the server and the client. When the password submitted matches the password in the json file, the server emits a `"login-success"` event to that client and with that event passes the json file used in the server. The client side script accepts that response and parses that data for use. Here's a sample:

**server.js** - Server side script

```
if (password == json.password) {
    io.on("connection", function(socket){
        socket.emit("login-success", json);
    }
}
```

**app.js** - Client side script

```
var socket = io("http://localhost:8888");
var username;
socket.on("login-success", function(json){
    username = JSON.parse(json).username;
}
```

This also means the data only has to be read in once, the object it's assigned to is just passed to the client via the TCP stream established between it and the server. Hoorah!

Thanks very much for the responses everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can respond an HTML file and when document is load, respond the json file,
for example if you use jquery as your client side framework:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get(URL_To_JsonFile,Params,function(data){
        //do somthing with json file
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Basically, my problem is the client doesn't know *which* json file to read in. My main query is the way  the server goes about letting the client know which json file to read in, based on the file matched to the value of username submitted in the POST request (if that makes sense?).

Comment: I think you might run into that problem in various other ways if the POST response (be it HTML or JS) doesn't include some sort of user token in some way - some encrypted string you share to specify that this client has successfully logged in. Usually it's a cookie.

Comment: @Katana314 Cookies are something I've never looked into, and don't really know how they work or what purpose they serve (in this context). So you're saying the server should create a cookie upon a successful login and then save that to the clients machine? How would I go about doing this? Cheers!

Comment: @Katana314 Moreover, is there a way to do all this cookie related stuff independent of other modules like express? Im trying to learn the nitty gritty see :)